# New Template: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1390

Tags: template, fatal-error

I recently installed a new template: MT Bejewelry, and this error comes out in the product page. These are the lines on the php file.

```
   /**
 * Get attribute text by its code
 *
 * @param $attributeCode Code of the attribute
 * @return string
 */
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()
        ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getSource()
                ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
```

Because of this error I can't see the Product Description.

How can I solve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your theme for a line like this:

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('some_attribute_code_here');
```

This only works if the attribute with the code specified above is of type select or multiselect.
If you say the problem is with the description then maybe you have something like

```
 echo $_product->getAttributeText('description');
```

If you do, this is wrong. you should replace it with

```
$description = $product->getDescription();
echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_description, 'description');
```

Comment: I don't know where to look exactly. I've found something similar with what you said to me but with 'mater' or 'gemstone' instead of 'description'.

Comment: then make sure that mater or gemstone are dropdown or multiselect attributes and their source model exists.